# отправка данных submit

Tags: php, html

Друзья, подскажите, если я использую тип инпута - submit, можно ли сделать так, чтобы данные отправлялись на одну страницу, а открывалась при этом бы другая?

Comment: Редирект добавить в обработчик сабмита, или можно с помощью js всё делать

Answer (score 1):

Можно в атрибуте формы action задать action="#", прописав скрипты, обрабатывающие форму, на этой же странице. При submit будет перезагружаться эта же страница

Либо, если нужна другая определенная страница, в файле обработчике, указанном в action, в конце после всего кода, обрабатывающего форму, прописать:

```
<?php
  header("Location: http://www.example.com/");
  exit;
?>
```

http://www.example.com/ - адрес страницы, которая будет открываться после submit

Comment: _Можно в атрибуте формы action задать action="#"_ - а можно и туда 1 напишу? :)

Comment: @InDevX не знаю, не пробовал) 
Наверное да

Comment: Я немного не понял как тогда написать скрипт который обрабатывает эту форму, по сути мне нужно чтобы отправлялись данные на страницу create.php
а открывалась бы совсем другая страница

P.S. как оказалось делать редирект в самом файле create.php нельзя, потому что тогда ломается вся логика

Comment: @АнтонКравцов Тогда мне надо посмотреть Ваш код - форму, обработчик, страницу конечную. Так я не понимаю, о какой ломающейся логике идет речь